Does there exist a proof of this claim that does not use Hilbert's Nullstellensatz
I am reading this paper, and there is a part I don't understand. Let $P_1,\dots,P_k$ be homogeneous complex polynomials, whose only common complex zero is $0$. At the bottom of page 56, it is claimed
"The only prime ideal containing $(P_1,\dots,P_k)$ (the ideal generated by $\{P_j, 1\leq j \leq k\}$) is the ideal of all polynomials which vanishes at $0$."
I think I can prove this claim using Hilbert's nullstellensatz. But this article says a little earlier (and repeats later) that it avoids Hilbert's nullstellensatz. So, my question is : can this claim be proved without Hilbert's nullstellensatz ? Maybe I am missing something obvious. After all, I am but an analyst, and my algebra-fu is rusty, but I don't see how it would be done.
PS : not sure about the tags. Sorry if they are not the most appropriate choice.

Is $(P_j)$ a single ideal generated by all the $P_j,$ or just generated by one $P_j?$ The wording just seems a little off there.

Presumably, this is in the ring of all polynomial, since in the ring of homogenous polynomials, all polynomials have a zero at $0?$

Sorry, this is indeed the ideal generated by all the $P_j$s ; I edited the question. Also, yes this is the ideal in the ring of all polynomials (this is how I understand the claim of the article, at least).

I could imagine that statement is more or less equivalent to the (weak) Nullstellensatz.

Yeah, after unfolding more of what is happening in the article before and after this claim, here is what the author does : "for every $1\leq j \leq n$, $X_j$ vanishes at $0$ [weird things happening] thus for some $s>0$, $X_j^s\in (P_1,\dots,P_k)$". So it is a Nullstelensatz after all. Considering this, I find dubious the author's claim that the Nullstelensatz is not used in the proof.
